# Postgres: Deadlock while inserting to a table when another process updating related row

Tags: postgresql, database-deadlocks

I have procedure p_add_payment() which do some operations and at the end peforms INSERT INTO to table "transaction" which have foreign keys to "user_store" and "user" tables. In a meantime there is an UPDATE query on "user" table.

TX1: INSERT INTO transaction(id, user_id, user_store_id) VALUES(1, 2, 3);
TX2: UPDATE user SET email = "xxx" WHERE id = 2;

so TX1 tries to insert row into transaction where foreign key user_id = 2, TX2 tries to update user with the same ID (2).

I noticed deadlocks in Postgres logs:

```
Detail: Process 383877 waits for ShareLock on transaction 791966314; blocked by process 384092. Process 384092 waits for ShareLock on transaction 791966330; blocked by process 383877.

 Process 383877: SELECT * FROM p_add_payment (...)

 Process 384092: UPDATE "user" SET "email" = 'sales@(...)
```

There is a way to skip locks when inserting into table "transaction"? I'm 100% sure that the related rows (user, user_store) wo be deleted or their primary keys won't change.

I'm not really familiar with deadlock so I don't know where the problem is and I'm just guessing it's a problem with lock during INSERT INTO "transaction"

Comment: The 383877 statement from the log file is not the one you report T1 doing.  Can you explain how a SELECT turns into an INSERT?

Comment: p_add_payment is a procedure which performs an INSERT statement (and a few things before this) and returns a row that inserted thats's why i perform SELECT * FROM p_add_payment to get result of this procedure